# Circle containing Most weighted points.

Tags: algorithms

Im trying to figure out an algorithm that, Given a Tv station with range of R and
N locations (N points with x,y coordinates) each location having a population P.The best placement of the tv Station so that its range will serve at least a A threshold of population.
My first thought was treating the tv station as a circle,find the points that it contains,calculate its population capacity,until i find a placement that fulfils
the capacity requirement.I also checked the smallest circle problem,but it doesnt
meet the requirements of current problems.The problem is, there can be infinite circles to examine,is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance